# Different AccuracyGoal for different variables

Tags: numerics

Is it possible to set different AccuracyGoals for different variables in numerical commands like FindRoot and NDSolve?

Comment: Not that I know of. Why do you need to do this though? Maybe there's a different approach...

Comment: Qualitatively different types of variables require different accuracy/precision -- settings that work for one are overkill for another.  I got the idea from using the VODE ODE solver, which allows different tolerance for each variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify only identical `AccuracyGoal`s for all the variables but what you wish is possible to achieve by changing the scales of the variables. For example if you wish `AccuracyGoal` for `x` to be `2` and for `y` to be `3` you need to replace `y` variable *in the model* by `y/10` and specify `AccuracyGoal -> 2`. After fitting you need to make backward transformation through dividing obtained fitted value for `y` by `10`. In such way you obtain `y` with `Accuracy` 3 and `x` with `Accuracy` 2.

P.S. I should mention here that `Accuracy` in *Mathematica* means the *absolute uncertainty*, not the *relative uncertainty*.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a good idea for FindRoot, but wouldn't work for NDSolve.